# AdMob Rewarded Video with Limit Ad Tracking/iOS

Tags: ios, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have read other topics on rewarded videos not being displayed because Limit Ad Tracking is turned on but I am still a bit unclear. Every time it is turned on there is no ad to display, when it is turned off the ad is displayed just fine. My question is as soon as my app is released and available for download, are users who have Limit Ad Tracking ever going to be presented with my rewarded video ad? If the user who has the Limit Ad Tracking turned on will not be presented with the reward ad, the entire way my app functions must be changed, since they will have to watch an ad to unlock certain rewards. So my question is with Limit Ad Tracking turned on will devices ever get the rewarded video ad presented?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.   How I handled this was to present an alert in the didFailToLoadWithError delegate method.  I simply ask the user to go to settings and turn Limit Ad Tracking off.  It's not ideal but it is a solution.

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    print("Reward based video ad failed to load.", error)
    // Show UIAlertController here
}
```